# Getting all possible string combinations with Perl

Tags: perl

Given a string for example 'rogerdavis' than it should convert it to 'rogerd@vis' or 'rogerdav!s' or 'rogerdavi$' or 'rogerd@v!$' and all possible combination and append it in a file. So basically  have to convert 'a' to '@', 's' to '$' and 'i' to '!' and use all possible combinations. This is to be done in Perl.

**Pseudocode**

- Create a new file
- Calculate number of occurrences of a,A,s,S,i,I (or
  we can    accept keyword only in small or in caps to simplify the
  switch case)
- Calculate total number of possibilities we can have by
  using    formula of combinations For total number of possibilities we
  perform the job on hand of    replacing character `a ->@`, `s->$`,
  `i-> I`
- add unique entry to the file

This is what came to my mind at first. Please help me because I know there's got to be an easy and simple way to do this thing:

1. Accept keyword in an array `keyword[ ]`
2. Calculate length of the array in `length_of_keyword`
3. Scan array `keyword[ ]` from left to right
       count =0;
       for(i=0; i
       }
4. Using count to calculate total number of possibilities

   ```
   total_poss =0;
   r= 1;
   new_count = count
   for (i = count; i > 0; i--)
   {
       // fact( ) will calculate factorial
       total_poss += fact(new_count)/(fact(r)*fact(new_count - r))  
       r++;
    }

   for (k=0; k<total_poss; total_poss++)
      copy array keyword[ ] in temporary array temp[ ];
      for (i=0; i< new_count; i++)
      {

          for (j = 0; j< lenght_of_keyword; j++)
          {
              if (temp[i] is equal to 'a' || 'A' || 's' || 'S' || 'i' || 'I' )
              {
                  switch (temp[j])

                      case i: tempt[i] = ! ;
                                 if ( modified array is equal to an entry in file)
                                     continue;
                                 else save in file; break;
                      case I: (same as above or we can have function for above code)
                    .
                    .// similarly for all cases
                    .
           }
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: There's the [`edit`](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/6995383/edit) button just under the tags in your question. Click on it to modify your question.

Comment: What's up with the non-wrapping lines in the question? Code formatting is for code, not pseudo-code without line-breaks.

Comment: i knw but i was nt able to upload it without formatting...anyways point is can anyone help me out

Comment: If you want people to read your question, you make it readable.

Comment: See my [Perl uni!@#$ script](http://training.perl.com/scripts/havshpx) for how I myself approached this sort of problem.

Comment: @tchrist : That's a `tr///` problem, right?

Answer (score 6):

I wanted to give [`List::Gen`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?List%3a%3aGen) a whirl. This problem provided the perfect excuse!

---

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use List::Gen;

my %symbol = ( a => '@', A => '@',
               i => '!', I => '!',
               s => '$', S => '$', );  # Symbol table

my $string = 'rogerdavis';
my @chunks = split /(?<=[ais])|(?=[ais])/i, $string;

# Turn into arrayrefs for cartesian function

@chunks = map { $_ =~ /^[ais]$/i ? [ $_, $symbol{$_} ] : [ $_ ] } @chunks;

my $cartesian = cartesian { join '', @_ } @chunks;  # returns a generator

say for @$cartesian;  # or 'say while < $cartesian >'
```

---

**Output**

> ```
> rogerdavis
> rogerdavi$
> rogerdav!s
> rogerdav!$
> rogerd@vis
> rogerd@vi$
> rogerd@v!s
> rogerd@v!$
> ```

Comment: [`List::Gen::Cookbook`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?List::Gen::Cookbook) will probably show a couple more ways to do this

Comment: @David : Heck, [Eric's](http://stackoverflow.com/users/189416/eric-strom) done a fantastic job in writing it. Piecing it together was a doddle.

Comment: Wow! thank u very much really appreciate for taking the time out for helping

Comment: glob from File::Glob already does the task (glob, it isn't just for matching files anymore, or since the beginning of UNIX).

Answer (score 5):

Use glob(3)'s multiple pattern support ({}) by replacing a with {a,@}, s with {s,$} and i with {i,!}, like the following:

```
my $str = 'rogerdavis';
my $glob = $str;
# set up replacement character map
my %replacements = (a => '@', s => '$', i => '!');
# add uppercase mappings
$replacements{uc $_} = $replacements{$_} for keys %replacements;
# replace 'character' with '{character,replacement}'
$glob =~ s/([asi])/{$1,$replacements{$1}}/ig;
my @list = glob($glob);
print join "\n", @list;
print "\n";
my $count = scalar(@list);
```

If the replacement character is a glob(7) metacharacter, then it should be escaped (`3 => '\}', e => '\['`, for example).

Update: You can replace the [asi] with results of running something like [Data::Munge](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Data-Munge)'s list2re, f.e.:

```
my $re = Data::Munge::list2re(keys %replacements);
$glob =~ s/($re)/{$1,$replacements{$1}}/ig;
```

Answer (score 1):

A fairly bare-bones implementation:

```
sub convert {
  my $keyword = shift @_;
  my $map = @_ ? $_[ 0 ] : \%MAP;
  my @parts = do {
    my $regex = do {
            my $letters = join('', keys %$map);
            qr/([$letters])/i;
    };
    split($regex, $keyword, -1);
  };
  my $n_slots = ( -1 + scalar @parts )/2;
  my $n_variants = 2 ** $n_slots;
  my @variants;
  my $i = 0;  # use $i = 1 instead to keep the original $keyword                                                          
              # out of the list of variants                                                                               
  while ( $i < $n_variants ) {
    my @template = @parts;
    my $j = 1;
    my $k = $i;
    for ( 1 .. $n_slots ) {
      $template[ $j ] = $map->{ lc $parts[ $j ] } if $k & 1;
      $j += 2;
      $k >>= 1;
    }
    push @variants, join( '', @template );
    $i++;
  }

  return \@variants;
}

sub main {
  my $keyword = shift @_;
  my $fh = @_ ? ( open( $_[ 0 ], 'a' ) or die $! ) : \*STDOUT;
  print $fh "$_\n" for @{ convert( $keyword ) };
}

main( $ARGV[ 0 ] );
```

Sample run:

```
% perl 6995383.pl rogerDaViS
rogerDaViS
rogerD@ViS
rogerDaV!S
rogerD@V!S
rogerDaVi$
rogerD@Vi$
rogerDaV!$
rogerD@V!$
```

Pardon the lack of comments and lack of error handling (rushed for time), but the basic idea is that if there are n slots that could be replaced, and assuming that there is exactly one possible alternative per slot, then there are 2^n variants (including the original keyword).  The bits in (the binary representation of) the `$i` index are used to keep track of which positions to replace at each iteration of the outer loop.  Hence, the iteration with `$i == 0` leaves the keyword unchanged.  (Therefore, if you don't want this "variant", just `shift` it out of the returned array.)

This is just a first crack at this.  In addition to comments and error handling, I'm sure that, with a bit more thought, this implementation could be improved/tightened significantly.

HTH...

Comment: Wow! thank u very much really appreciate for taking the time out for helping